# MVC Invalid object name 'dbo.Staffs' error

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, object

I got the error `Invalid object name 'dbo.Staffs'.` but I'm not sure why. I actually deleted and recreated my database with EF because previously I had other errors. But I'm quite sure I recreated it correctly because I've done it in the same way for other programs and it works fine.

**.edmx database diagram**
[image]

**Controller**

```
    private StaffPortalDBEntities1 db = new StaffPortalDBEntities1();
    SqlConnection cnn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["StaffPortalDBConnectionString"].ConnectionString);

    [Authorize]
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var userEmail = User.Identity.Name;
        var model = db.Staffs.Where(i => i.Email == userEmail).Include("Histories").Include("CurrentApplications").FirstOrDefault();

        return View(model);
    }
```

I got the error is for the line `var model = db.Staffs.Where(i => i.Email == userEmail).Include("Histories").Include("CurrentApplications").FirstOrDefault();`

**Generated Staff class**

```
public partial class Staff
{
    public Staff()
    {
        this.Histories = new HashSet<History>();
        this.CurrentApplications = new HashSet<CurrentApplication>();
    }

    public int StaffID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public Nullable<decimal> AllocatedLeave { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> BalanceLeave { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<History> Histories { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<CurrentApplication> CurrentApplications { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: It seems something is out of whack with your pluralization convention. Try adding a `[Table(Name = "Staff")]` attribute above your `Staff` class.

Comment: @StuartLC Hi I tried it but I'm still getting the same error D:

Comment: Looks like you have skrewed up the Model creation somewhere, does intelisense give you Staffs? Have you checked the Model? Why do you use so many properties for the Primary Key on Current Applications?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var model = db.Staffs.Where(i => i.Email == userEmail).Include(x=>x.Histories).Include(x=>x.CurrentApplications).FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: For the line var model = db.Staffs.Where(i => i.Email == userEmail).Include("Histories").Include("CurrentApplications").FirstOrDefault();. Even when i tried yours i get the same error. I get it when i try to access the Index view.

Comment: check your model which you used inside index view.Probably the name for model is wrong.

Comment: In my view I'm currently using this [at]model LeaveApplication.Models.CurrentAndHist but since I am just returning a model now from my controller what do I use? :O

Comment: since you are using "var model", I am not sure about your model type. find it and add the type by @using on top of your view.